# My shell prompt changed ... without prompting

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, catalina, bash

I'm still running bash on MacOS Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101). Sorry.

Recently, I don't know why, the prompt in my bash sessions is acting up. There appears at the start of every prompt the string `(base)`:

`(base) MyComputer:~ myname$`

The result of `cat /etc/bashrc` is:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

I don't see anything related in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`.

The result of `echo $PS1` is:

```
(base) \h:\W \u\$
```

I have no local `~/.bashrc`, and the result of `grep 'PS1' ~/.*` is empty, notwithstanding grep errors. That is to say, I'm not setting the PS1 variable in my home directory that I can see. I certainly haven't written code to do so.

I can change the prompt manually in one bash session:

`PS1="\h:\W \u\$"`

and that works for that session. But a new Terminal tab or window just gives me the `(base)` prefix once more.

I don't see anything in the preferences panes of the MacOS app `Terminal`, which is the app I use. Although... I did just launch an `xterm` and there the prompt is simply `bash-3.2$` .

Can somebody help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: Did you install Anaconda/python recently? Does `conda deactivate` change anything? Do you have `~/.profile`?

Comment: Also, check for `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login`.

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/q/1026383.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you installed Anaconda/python recently. Run

```
conda decactive
```

to remove the `(base)` label (and deactivate `conda` of course).

PS: You may be using `zsh` instead of `bash`, so maybe you should look into `.zshrc` and `.zprofile`.

Comment: Deactivating anaconda was the trick, thanks! Definitely still on bash.